# React: can't change the component using a toolbar with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a toolbar that contains a search bar and some buttons that change the path using history.push(). Problem I have is the path is changed but the relevant component I have specified in my `<Route />` doesn't render.

I imagine this is a result of my Route with the toolbar not being part of the same router. If i try to put my toolbar in the , only the toolbar will render.

```
<CoreLayout store={store}>
  <Route {...Toolbar(store)} />
  <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
        <Route ... />
        <Route ... />
        <Route ... />
     </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
</CoreLayout
```

My CoreLayout containers the header, footer etc that I want in every page.

Answer (score 0):

The component need to be child of the same router provider, IE:

```js
<Provider store={store}>
  <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <App />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </LanguageProvider>
</Provider>,
```